# Is there a performance impact when use PHP_INT_MAX with array?

Tags: php, arrays

For example I have the following code

```
$array = [];
$array[0] = 0;
$array[1] = 1;
$array[2] = 'max';

foreach ($array as $value) {
    // code
}
```

I want to know is there any performance impact when I use PHP_INT_MAX as the index of a array like so.

```
$array = [];
$array[0] = 0;
$array[1] = 1;
$array[PHP_INT_MAX] = 'max';

foreach ($array as $value) {
    // code
}
```

Regardless whether yes or not, anybody can tell me the reason? Thanks!

Comment: is there any reason why you want to use PHP_INT_MAX? or is this just a general question?

Comment: Yes, I'm using WordPress, and I want to make sure the `add_action()` add my function that has the lowest priority.Is this the right way to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the array still only has 3 elements, so only 3 elements exist in memory.

It doesn't really matter what the keys are for those elements, though there's a slight memory overhead for long string keys because PHP maintains the key as well as the value and longer strings use more memory than shorter strings; but in this case, your keys are integers which are fixed size, whether the value is -1, 0, 98 or PHP_INT_MAX